# Entity Framework select on IQueryable throwing "must be reducible node"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I have this query where predicate is `Expression<Func<Property, bool>>` and the whole query returns an `IQueryable`:

```
var query = _db.PropertyRepository.Get(predicate)
               .Include(x => x.Info)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.Address)
               .Include(x => x.TransactionListingAgents)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.Agent)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.Person)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.Contact)
```

I'd like to perform a select on that `IQueryable` to project to a DTO, because I need to do some data manipulation with that data. So I have this other query

```
query.Select(x => new BasePropertyDTO() {
    Id = x.Id,
    StreetNumber = x.Info.Address.StreetNumber,
    Street = x.Info.Address.StreetName,
});
```

However, it throws an exception

> must be reducible node

My workaround was doing `ToList()` before the `Select()` and that doesn't throw the exception anymore , but now I'm grabbing data that I don't need.

I have found out that the issue comes when I try to project on my select properties from Info navigation property or any navigation property, even though I have the `Include()` calls.

Any ideas on why this is behaving this way or what's wrong with my queries?

Complete query after upgrading to 1.1.0:

```
query.ToList().Select(x => new BasePropertyDTO() {
                Id = x.Id,
                StreetNumber = (x.Info != null && x.Info.Address != null) ? x.Info.Address.StreetNumber : "",
                Street = (x.Info != null && x.Info.Address != null) ? x.Info.Address.StreetName : "",
                City = (x.Info != null && x.Info.Address != null) ? x.Info.Address.City : "",
                AgentName = x.TransactionListingAgents.Where(t => t.Agent != null && t.Agent.Person != null && t.Agent.Person.Contact != null && t.ListingId == x.Id && t.BrokerageId == x.BrokerageId).Select(a => a.Agent.Person.Contact.FullName).FirstOrDefault()
            });
```

The AgentName part throws

> An item with the same key has already been added

If I remove that, I still get the

> must be reducible node

Answer (score 1):

EF team has fixed this issue on Entity Framework Core 1.1.So you have to use that version to avoid the above issue.

[**Entity Framework Core 1.1**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/)

**Git Issue** which was solved on the above version :

[**'must be reducible node' when aggregating over a join**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5812)

Comment: If this is the case, you should link to the specific issue.

Comment: @Sampath, I have updated to 1.1.0 and now I get another exception: An item with the same key has already been added. If I remove the columns that throw that error, I still get the "must be reducible node" exception

Comment: Oh..hope you can open a new issue on Git : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new

Comment: I am getting this issue in .net core v1.1.1. Can someone please tell, is it fixed?